# Разбор предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Слово "вот" в предложении — это обстоятельство?

Comment: Алекс, а Вы слышали о существовании знаков препинания?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, нужно бы посмотреть предложение, но слово"вот" всегда было частицей, а в предложении может входить в состав какого-либо члена предложения. Обстоятельством может оказаться частица "вот-вот": Он вот-вот придет.(Он скоро придет)